# Matrix Equation, Solving for Variables.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm going through my exercises, and came across a problem that wasn't covered in our lectures. Here's the question:

$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
a-b & b+c\\
3d+c & 2a-4d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
=
$
$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 1\\
7 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$

What I have done so far is:

$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
a-b-8 & b+c-1\\
3d+c-7 & 2a-4d-6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
=
$
$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$

---

And the solving for variables,

$$
a-b-8 = 0
$$
$$
a-b = 8
$$
$$
a = \frac{8}{-b}
$$

---

$$
b+c-1=0
$$
$$
b+c=1
$$
$$
b=\frac{1}{c}
$$

---

$$
3d+c-7=0
$$
$$
3d+c=7
$$
$$
3d=\frac{7}{c}
$$
$$
d=\frac{7}{3c}
$$

---

$$
2a-4d-6=0
$$
$$
2a-4d=6
$$
$$
\frac{16}{-2b}-\frac{28}{12c}=6
$$

---

Am I going about this correctly? Or am I just doing this completely incorrect?

Comment: Whoa. Yes, quite a few very basic mistakes here. In fact, every single one of your subproblems is wrong; you are dividing when you should be subtracting. I hope you will not take offense but I would strongly recommend a conference with your instructor.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant No none taken, we haven't done anything like this in our labs or during the lectures, and I was just guessing as to what I should be doing.

Comment: Cool. It does seem rather unfortunate that they would foist this multiequation problem on you before you had mastered isolating variables in single equations.

Comment: I'm taking this course during our Spring semester, and it's normally a 4 month long class, however during the Spring it's crammed down into only 2 months. So this is most likely why we are skipping some of these types of questions. Thank you for your feedback though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 1: $a-b=8$ is not the same as $a = \frac{8}{-b}$ but $a = 8 + b$

Error 2: $b+c=1$ is not the same as $b = \frac{1}{c}$ but $b = 1-c$

Error 3: $3d+c=7$ ... same as errors 1 and 2

Error 4: $2a-4d=6$ Incorrect substitution because of previous errors. Fix the previous errors and then subsititue to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

How familiar are you with basic linear algebra? As @response has posted, you have numerous algebra mistakes. However, as for the method used to solve the problem, I think it's worth noting that you can easily transform this system to one more familiar looking and then use standard technique of Gaussian elimination. That is, rewrite the system as follows:

$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 &  0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$
$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
=
$
$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
8 \\
1\\
7 \\
6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$

And then solve.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I didn't even think of trying to solve it this way. I'll keep it in mind for the rest of my exercises.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is follow the solution given by @Alex Wertheim. Let me show you a tedious substitution method to solve this. From $a_{11}$ we have $$b=a-8$$ (dividing by $a$ or $b$ is invalid as we may have zeros). Now from $a_{12}$ entry we have $$c=-b+1=-a+9,$$ and using $a_{21}$ $$d=\dfrac{-c+7}{3}=\dfrac{a-2}{3}.$$ Finally from the last entry $a_{22}$ we have $$a-2d=a-\dfrac23(a-2)=3.$$ Find $a$ from this simple linear equation and substitute back to find $b, c$ and $d.$